# How use REGEXREPLACE in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-replace

I import data via IMPORTXML and get it in the form as shown in column A:B
How can I use REGEXPREPLACE to bring them into the form as I showed in columns D:F ?
With the price I tried
ARRAYFORMULA(--REGEX REPLACE(IMPORT XML(I 2;"//span[@class='tooltip_3']");"\D";)),
but in in this form, I have extra zeros at the end.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nx4m_qMRA5Fm1lr18p2Mvt6Ds96_Kay-zJKGVZn2Uaw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 SPLIT(IMPORTXML("https://www.rsi-llc.ru/catalog/195/";"//h2[@class='product-item__title']"); " | ";) \  
 REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("https://www.rsi-llc.ru/catalog/195/";"//span[@class='tooltip_3']"); " "; ); "\d+")*1;
 SPLIT(IMPORTXML("https://www.rsi-llc.ru/catalog/100/";"//h2[@class='product-item__title']"); " | ";) \  
 REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("https://www.rsi-llc.ru/catalog/100/";"//span[@class='tooltip_3']"); " "; ); "\d+")*1})
```

[image]